# Prove that $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is sequential and not first countable

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, quotient-spaces

Let's say I have a a space X, the quotient space of R (the reals) obtained by identifying all points of Z (the integers).

How do I prove that X is sequential but not first countable?

(sequential means every sequentially open set is open.  I was thinking I might be able to show that R is sequential and then that any quotient space of a sequential space is sequential. Not sure how to show it's not first countable.)

I need help not just with the idea, but with actually writing out the rigorous proof.  Thank you.

Comment: Can someone steer me in the right direction here?

Comment: I suggest you that try to draw an sketch of what is $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. And convince yourself that the point $\mathbb{Z}$ in the quotient can not have a contable basis.

Comment: How would I go about that?  R/Z looks like a circle, no?

Comment: What about sequential?

Comment: I misused the notation $R/Z$. Sorry. The space $X$ looks like an infinity loops about $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I don't understand. Is the definition given in the following link? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space

Comment: Ok I'm really poor at constructing proofs to be honest and I fail to see how I could show that there is no countable basis around any point, and also how to show something like that is sequential. Can you provide a guideline or reasons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in comments  you can imagine the space $X$ as an infinity loops passing through a point (this point is $\mathbb{Z}$). Remember that a set $U$ in $X$ is open if and only iff $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open. To prove that $X$ is not a first countable space you should find an element in $X$ such that for every countable collection of neighborhoods is not enough to be a basis, i.e, there exist another open not in the basis which contains the point but does not exist any open in the countable collection contained in the open.

You should have the following things in mind:

1. The open set of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $X$ are those sets image by $\pi$ of a union of neighborhoods of each integer. I mean for example a union like $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(-\frac{1}{2}+n,n+\frac{1}{2})$.
2. For $n\in \mathbb{N}$. We define the function $f(n)=-\frac{n-1}{2}$ if $n$ odd and $f(n)=\frac{n}{2}$ if $n$ is even. We use this later.

I claim that the point $\mathbb{Z}$ which has not a countable basis. To prove this take a countable collection $\{U_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of neighborhoods of $\mathbb{Z}$ (remember that this is a point in the quotient space).

Now we are going to construct a new open $U$ in $X$ which does not contain any $U_n$. For 1. the open $\pi^{-1}(U_1)$ contains a open interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ about $0$. Choose an interval $(-\delta_1,\delta_1)$ contains in $(-\epsilon, \epsilon) $ (and then in $U_1$ ). Now $\pi^{-1}(U_2)$ contains an interval $(-\epsilon+1,\epsilon+1)$ and choose an interval $(-\delta_2+1,1+\delta_2)$ contained in $(-\epsilon+1,\epsilon+1)$ (and then in $U_2$ ).

Following this process we get a family $\{(-\delta_n+f(n),\delta_n+f(n))\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that  $(-\delta_n+f(n),f(n)+\delta_n)\subset \pi^{-1} (U_n )$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then for 1. the set $U=\pi\left[\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{n}}(-\delta_n+f(n),f(n)+\delta_n)\right] $ is open in $X$. Prove that $U$ does not contain any $U_n$ and then $X$ is not first countable.

The second problem is rather easy. Because of the definition of quotient space if you take a set $U$ in $X$ and prove that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open then you can assure that $U$ is open. Furthermore, you have that $\mathbb{R}$ is sequentially open, then if you prove that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is sequentially open then $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is indeed open.

My principal suggestion to you is: Draw a picture!

Comment: You claim that U=π[⋃n∈n(δn+f(n),f(n)+δn)].  Is this a mistake? Should it be U=π[⋃n∈n(-δn+f(n),f(n)+δn)] ?  I'm not sure I understood parts of this.. How can I prove that U does not contain any Un?

Comment: For each $U_n$ take a interval such that $(f(n)-\delta_n,f(n)+\delta_n)\subset (f(n)-\epsilon, f(n)+\epsilon)\subset\pi^{-1}(U_n)$. And deduce that $U_n\not\subset U $. ($\epsilon$ greater than  $\delta_n$)

Comment: Wait, you claim that U2 contains (−ϵ+1,ϵ+1), but then that f(n) is negative if it is odd (f(n)=−(n−1)/2) but positive if it is even (f(n)=n/2).  Is that correct?   Then you say "we get a family {(−δn+f(n),n+δ+f(n))} but where is the n+δ coming from here?

Comment: This was another typo, try to find them and not to confuse yourself with them. Sorry.

Comment: It's fine I just wanted to confirm f(x)= - (n-1)/2 is supposed to be negative right?

Comment: Thank you for all the help

Comment: The idea of the function $f(n)$ is to be a bijection between the natural numbers and the integers. And $f$ is negative is $n$ (except for $1$) is odd and is positive if $n$ is even.

Comment: Why not just start with a local base at the point Z of the quotient space that is indeed by the entire set of integers? WLOG that is correct if there's a countable local base at that point, and then you can avoid the whole confusing business about the map f.